# After upgrade to iOS 11, iOS App not receiving APNS message when in Background

Tags: ios

After upgrading iOS device to IOS 11 Beta version, my app has stopped receiving APNS message when it is in background. It does receive the message when it is in foreground. As per the device logs, APNS messages are being delivered to the device and are available in the notification center.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: iOS 11 is still in beta, so this kind of bugs are prone to happen

Comment: Yes I see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the global thread to jump onto. Not resolved, but has to do with iOS11 throttling / no-delivery of notifications in certain circumstances. Actually a lot of circumstances.

Very painful, as we depend on the delivery of silent pushes  when app is active.

[Silent pushes not delivered to the app on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11)