# iOS 10.3 to iOS 11 upgrade : User stop receiving silent push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios11

I have many users complaining that when they migrated from iOS 10.3.3 to iOS 11 launched yesterday, they stopped receiving silent push notifications.

One thing is to be noted that, I have a setting in NSUSerDefaults if I have already asked the user for registering for push notifications. And I do :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Only if the user hasn't been asked before.

Now if user had already registered for notifications when he was on iOS 10.3.3, and upgrades to iOS 11, the code `registerUserNotificationSettings:settings` will never be called for him, until he reinstalls. Could that be an issue? However, I believe it is unnecessary for him to register again as he already is.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: iOS 11 bug - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622932-registerusernotificationsettings):

> It is recommended that you call this method before you schedule any
>   local notifications or register with the push notification service.

So it is advised to call it at least once per app launch, but before your server sends the push notification.