# App receives notification but UIApplicationDelegate method isn't called in first session

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My app receives push notifications normally but none of the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods are called (looking at `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` specifically). This only happens in the first session of the app (the session where user approves push notifications).
If I kill the app and run it again, I still receive the notifications but then the delegate methods are called correctly.

How is this possible, has anyone face this problem before? It's a pretty basic implementation of push notifications.

Comment: not sure, but I'm guessing your tokens weren't registered early enough, and you closing the app or something else, triggers it to register the tokens...

Comment: just to got you right - your code isn't called anymore after terminating your app? for example - application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:) -> if that's the case, please have a look at the following stackoverflow topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330053/ios11-swift-silent-push-background-fetch-didreceiveremotenotification-is-not/46392357#46392357

Answer (score 0):

To receive push notifications you have to register your token beforehand. If you are only receiving notifications after the second run I assume that you are sending your token to your service when you close the app or something.

You can use this to check the exact moment in which you are obtaining your notifications token:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")
}
```

Try to get the token and send a push notification manually to that token from your service after you obtain it.