# Push notification works only when app launched with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, push

I have a big problem, I set up (with great difficulty) push notifications on my iOS project. I decided to receive the data of the notification in the "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method of the "AppDelegate" then to create it programmatically (in order to carry out mandatory personal treatment). Everything works perfectly, only when I launch my application without the help of Xcode, I no longer receive the notifications, the notification creation code is not executed. I do not know what to do ...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping 
(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let body = userInfo["body"]

    print(userInfo)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = body! as! String
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 
1, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "idt", content: 
content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, 
withCompletionHandler: nil)

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Thanks you very much

Comment: This issue is linked to an existing Apple bug, if your testing device has iOS11 installed. Are you using iOS11 for testing? Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330053/ios11-swift-silent-push-background-fetch-didreceiveremotenotification-is-not

Comment: I use latest ios 11.0.3

Comment: yes, than it is the current iOS11 (incl. 11.0.1 , 11.0.2& 11.0.3) - the issue will be fixed with iOS11.1, which should be delivered this or next week

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS11 swift silent push (background fetch, didReceiveRemoteNotification) is not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330053/ios11-swift-silent-push-background-fetch-didreceiveremotenotification-is-not)

Comment: I will wait ...

Comment: If i test with ios 8/9/10 device, it will work ?

Comment: yes it should work then

Comment: I would also like to say that when I kill my app from multitask, the notifications do not arrive anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch your app from a notification you need to check the *launchOptions* in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to see if `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` is present.

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionsremotenotificationkey?language=objc):

> The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the remote notification. See the description of application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: for further information about handling remote notifications.
>   This key is also used to access the same value in the userInfo dictionary of the notification named UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification.

Once you determine that the launch contains a notification, invoke your notification handler method with the *notification payload* obtained from *launchOptions*.

[What you have now](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application), which is `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` is only triggered when the app is already running:

> If the app is running, the app calls this method to process incoming remote notifications. The userInfo dictionary contains the aps key whose value is another dictionary with the remaining notification

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your project settings/Capabilities - Background Modes - Remote notifications

Answer (score 0):

Enable Remote notifications in Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1,
        "badge" : 0,
        "Priority" : 10
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

The notification’s priority:

10 The push message is sent immediately.

The remote notification must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the device. It is an error to use this priority for a push that contains only the `content-available` key.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW1

Answer (score -1):

When the device is running and connected to Xcode, the system treats silent notifications as high-priority simply because the OS is smart enough to know "You must be debugging your app, so I will treat your app's tasks as high priority".

When the device is disconnected from Xcode, the system then treats silent notifications as low-priority. Therefore, it doesn't guarantee their delivery in order to improve battery life.