# iOS 11 how to keep the app active in the background

Tags: ios

Before iOS 11, there are many ways to keep the app active in the background, but iOS 11 will not work and will be killed after about 173 seconds. Is there any way to keep the app active in the background of iOS 11?

Comment: It is fixed from iOS 11.1. Read it: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330053/ios11-swift-silent-push-background-fetch-didreceiveremotenotification-is-not  2) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86034

Comment: Just add the permission you need in plist. NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription/NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription/NSLocationAlwaysUsageDes‌​cription for BaiduMap，it doesn't work

Comment: Use NSLocationAlwaysUsageDes‌​‌​cription for always use. Search how to use it in plist. And your problem is a bug of apple's. They solved it from iOS 11.1

Comment: You mean that iOS 11 can not keep the APP active in the background？