# Push Notification is not working in iOS-11 in my Phone gap application

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap

my existing project till iOS-10 notification is working fine  ,But in iOS-11 it is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455236/8497400
this apparently seems to be fixed in iOS 11.1 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 11.1 beta 1 was just released and they mention: "Notifications Resolved Issues • Silent push notifications are processed more frequently. (33278611)