# iOS 11 Push notifications do not work with PushWoosh

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios11, pushwoosh

I have a question regarding `iOS 11` Push notifications.

Our app doesn’t receive Push notification after the update to iOS 11. It was working fine in iOS 10.

The provisioning files, code signs, and environment for distribution (App Store, TestFlight) have not changed.

Could you let me know what else we can check?

Comment: Have you tried obtaining the push notification token and used something APNS tester or other test utility to directly send it?

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Hi, Mr. Currie. Thanks for the comment. I tried, but any push notification not comes. And I added some logger to handlers(UNUserNotificationCenter). But I couldn't see any logs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about APNS support issues that should be directed at Apple Support.

Comment: I have an own Push Server and I am pushing notification toward apps on iOS 10/11 continuously, so it is definitely not APNS... please provide more information about how you have set up the actual connection or generated the certs, because that is _too board_ at the moment.

Comment: We have been having this problem as well using {"aps":{"content-available":1}} as the payload.  It just doesn't trip the delegate methods foreground or background.  We need the app to wake and download in the background so this is killing us.  Which payload are you using?

Comment: Edited this question to include the critical detail that PushWoosh is the APNS provider. I found this from SO question by way of PW support forum link here: https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/4627/ios-11-push-notification-not-works. Also I have a PW-specific resolution below.

Comment: @sinwoobang this question should have "marked as duplicate" removed because the referenced answer does not pertain to provider-specific PushWoosh issue nor the PushWoosh SDK upgrade remedy and is not a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the PushWoosh iOS SDK, you will need to upgrade to [v5.3.7](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-ios-sdk/releases/tag/5.3.7) or higher for iOS 11 compatibility. If using Cordova (PhoneGap), upgrade your plugin to [v7.0.7](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin/releases/tag/7.0.7) or higher.

iOS major version releases involve APNS architectural breaking changes and PushWoosh SDKs and plugins must be upgraded accordingly. This was the case with at least iOS 10 and 11 now. Expect more of the same for iOS 12 one day.

Comment: I resolved it by update SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are few checklist, you should check

- Ensure your provider has valid APNS certificates
- Make sure app has been registered with APNS server successfully.
- Your app sends latest device token to the app’s associated provider. Never cache device tokens in your app; instead, get them from the system when you need them. **APNs issues a new device token to your app when certain events happen.** e.g

  > when a user restores a device from a backup, when the user installs your app on a new device, and when the user reinstalls the operating system
- Make sure payload does not exceed the maximum limit. APNs refuses notifications whose payload exceeds the maximum allowed size. Check payload size:

  > - For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is 4KB (4096 bytes).
  > - For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum size is 5KB (5120 bytes)
- Make sure payload contains an `aps` dictionary with a simple alert message. The `acme2` key contains an array of app-specific data.

  ```
  {
      "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" },
      "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
  }
  ```

Thanks!