# APNS Silent Remote Notification not triggering - SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, apple-push-notifications, ios11

Scenarios:

**1) Silent or Normal payload when App's in Foreground:**

- Nothing happens

**2) Silent payload when App's in Background:**

- Nothing happens

**3) Normal payload when App's in Background:**

1. If User click the notification to open the App.

   - triggers the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`
2. If user open the App clicking the App icon:

   - Nothing happens

These are the payloads I'm using for the APNs:

***Normal payload:*** .

```
{  
  "aps":{  
    "alert":"andre test",
    "badge":0,
    "sound":"default",
    "content-available":1
  },
  "acme-syncalarm":"true"
}
```

***Silent payload:*** .

```
{  
  "aps":{  
    "content-available":1
  },
  "acme-syncalarm":"true"
}
```

I've implemented the Remote Push Notification using this code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Receeeeeeeeived: \(userInfo)")
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 11

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

I also implemented this to check if the App is recovering from a kill state (as I've read in some Questions too), but the code never enters the `print(rn)`line.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if let rn = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
            print(rn)
        }
 }
```

**EDIT 1** -
I have also enabled Remote Notifications in background mode for the App.

What do I have to do to cover the "Nothing Happens" Scenarios? 1 , 2 and 3.2 ?

Comment: what iOS version are you using?

Comment: If you are using iOS 11 then connect your iPhone to your mac and watch the device logging as you send the push. Search for the term pushLaunch in the device logging and post what it says.

Comment: 11.1 ... I’ve just updated to 11.1.1 but now I have to update my Xcode to test again... :/ I forgot I shouldn’t update the phone before the Xcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some notes:**

- "If user open the App clicking the App icon: Nothing happens" <-- That's expected, because you didn't interact with any notification directly. Imagine if you had 5 notifications arrived. How would you know which notification you should process...
- normal payload won't have any key named `content-available`. So that again is a silent notification. Can you first see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)?

**Some suggestions:**

- Make sure you've enabled Remote Notifications in background mode. Like this:

[image]

- Additionally See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796613/silent-pushes-not-delivered-to-the-app-on-ios-11). iOS 11 initial releases were buggy for silent notifications. Make sure you have the latest version for your testing, otherwise it won't work. If you have an iOS 10 device, then first try testing with that...
- Make sure you have Background App refresh and notifications available on your device. To see how to do it, refer to my linked answer.
- Are you creating the payload yourself or you're using FireBase? If you're using Firebase then some of the keys change...and you must adjust accordingly.
- make sure you've set some object as the `delegate` of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` e.g.:

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = delegateObject`

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let content = notification.request.content
    // Process notification content

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge]) // Display notification as regular alert and play sound
}
```

<sub>Code copied from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250).</sub>

If you don't do such then you won't be *showing* any notification when the app is in the foreground. This should resolve the issue of when app is in foreground and you've received a *normal* remote notification.

Comment: I'm creating by myself the payload, in my server, and for normal APN, It work well

Comment: In your question you said it didn't work correct for normal APN ie in your scenario 1. so does it work or not?

Comment: When Foreground doesn’t work... only works when in background and not silent

Comment: doing some tests here, I only implemented the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` and now is working. Seems that the problem really was the initial iOS 11 version. Now with iOS 11.1.1 the problem doesn't exist anymore