# iphoneX (11.2.1) Unable to receive silent notification

Tags: ios, iphone-x

It is normal for other devices to receive silence notifications
iphoneX (11.2.1) Unable to receive silent notification, but normal remote notification can be received, but still quietly notify the callback method
No problems with the certificate Development and production of other devices are pushed normal
Only iphoneX problems

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in iOs 11 that affects silent notifications. For some reason the notification not being delivered if the app is in suspended mode.Here is the thread : [Silent pushes not delivered to the app on iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44796613/1090238)