# Silent Push Notifications doesn't work properly on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

Does anyone else have troubles with silent push notifications on iOS 14 (latest beta). We use silent PNs for some sort of minimal syncing between devices via backend, and it works well on all iOS versions except iOS 14. I wrote "doesn't work properly" because sometimes they do work, but usually they are not delivered to iOS devices (response code from Apple while sending them is 200, means everything is ok).

UPD: seems like it's iOS issue, and also seems like it's fixed in iOS 14.2

Comment: Having same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @AtWork no, I really I don't have any clue what it might be. Hopefully today we will have new set of beta's, maybe it's an iOS issue. Going to wait and see

Comment: 14.2 didn't change anything for me, still no silent pushes at all, even after waiting 24 hours. iPad Pro 9.7" Wi-Fi

Comment: The answer in this post worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64690793/451383

Answer (score -1):

I experiencing same issue and this is critical for my app (I use silent pushes while in foreground to deliver messages to user)

I just installed iOS 14.2 beta and silent pushes work ok there (bug fixed). So looks like this is iOS 14.0 bug and apple knows about it and fixed already in beta.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference on 14.2 beta, my app is still not getting any silent pushes when in background, only gets them in foreground. From examining dasd output in Console, the Notes app does recent background pushes ok though.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you got it to work on 14.2? I'm not getting a single background push. iPad Pro 9.7" Wi-Fi

Comment: @malhal I tested only in foreground. Background silent pushes always were not reliable.